# How to determine mean VIIRS Nighttime Day/Night Band Composites Version 1 for each district (county)?

Tags: coordinate-system, spatial-analyst, reducers, night-time-images

How to determine mean VIIRS Nighttime Lights for each district (county) shapefile attached ?

The exported csv file does not contain required results!

```
var start = ee.Date('2017-01-01');
var end = ee.Date('2017-12-31');
var night_img = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG')
.filterDate(start, end) 
.select('avg_rad')
.first();
```